# Haskell under IOS 5: suppressing output

Tags: ios, haskell, ios5, io

I want to embed the Haskell engine into IOS5 app.
How to suppress Haskell console output for functions deriving from Show?

Comment: `Show` is for converting to a `String`, it does not generate any output.

Comment: A function derived from `Show` will not print anything to the console.  The only Haskell functions that can possibly print are ones that have a type ending in `IO a`.

Comment: Ok. Anyway - can anyone figure out scenario that requires suppressing of printed output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [silently](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/silently) package. It allows you to prevent `IO a` action to output into the `stdout` or any other `Handler`.